# Unwanted infinite loop in my game code. How to break out of it?

Tags: java, loops

I've figured out most of the code myself so far. I'm trying to make a little text based game. What I'm having trouble with is that I can't seem to get the random number roll to loop correctly. When it loops, it just loops the last thing that was rolled. Here is my code, the entire thing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

//Setting the variables for monsters
class monster {
    int health;
    String name;
    int damage;
}

//Setting the Variables that the player has
class Player {
    String name;
    int health;
    int damage;
}


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Creating a scanner to receive user input
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Creating Monsters
    monster Goblin = new monster();
    Goblin.name = "Goblin";
    Goblin.health = 5;
    Goblin.damage = 1;

    monster Orc = new monster();
    Orc.name = "Orc";
    Orc.health = 8;
    Orc.damage = 3;

    //Creating player stats
    Player Player = new Player();
    Player.name = "";
    Player.health = 15;
    Player.damage = 3;

    //////////////////////////////////////

    //Beginning of the game
    System.out.println("Hello adventurer. What is your name?");

    //Receive user input for their name
    String Username = scanner1.nextLine();
    Player.name = Username;

    //Message to restate player's name
    System.out.println("Ah, so your name is " + Username + ". Pleasure to meet you.");

    //Continuing description.
    System.out.println("Sorry to say, but there are more pressing matters at hand.");
    System.out.println("The nearby town of Notsosafe has been overrun by monsters!");
    System.out.println("Please go and help clear out the monsters there.");
    System.out.println("What is your weapon of choice? The Sword and shield? Greatsword? or Staff?");

    //Check for user input
    String weapon = scanner1.nextLine();

    //Check for which stats to apply
    while(true)
        if(weapon.equals("Sword and shield")){
            Player.damage = 3 + 2;
            Player.health = 15 + 3;
            break;
        }
        else if(weapon.equals("Greatsword")){
            Player.damage = 3 + 5;
            break;
        }
        else if(weapon.equals("Staff")){
            Player.damage = 3 + 1;
            Player.health = 15 + 5;
            break;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("We don't seem to have that, Please pick what we have.");
            weapon = scanner1.nextLine();
        }
    //Displays the Player's stats
    System.out.println("Your stats are now:");
    System.out.println("Attack: " + Player.damage);
    System.out.println("Health: " + Player.health);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Now that you have selected your weapon, Go and save the town of Notsosafe!");

    //Rolls random number to decide encounter
    Random dice = new Random();
    int randomNum = dice.nextInt((6-1) + 1) + 1;
    System.out.println(randomNum);

    int roll = 0;
    //Actions corresponding to random roll and which actions to take
    while(true)
        if(roll < 10){
    switch(randomNum){

    case 1:
        System.out.println("You've traveled some miles without any encounter.");

        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("You've traveled some miles without any encounter.");

        break;

    case 3:
        System.out.println("You've traveled some miles without any encounter.");

        break;

    case 4:
        System.out.println("You've run into a goblin! Attack or Defend?");
        String action = scanner1.nextLine();
        while(Goblin.health > 0){
            if(action.equals("Attack")){
                Goblin.health = Goblin.health - Player.damage;
                System.out.println("You've done " + Player.damage + " damage to Goblin. Goblin has "+ Goblin.health + " health remaining.");
                while(true){
                if(Goblin.health <= 0){
                    System.out.println("You have slain the Goblin! Continue to move forward.");
                    break;
                }
                    else{

                        Player.health = Player.health - Goblin.damage;
                        System.out.println("Goblin attacked you for " + Goblin.damage + " damage.");
                        System.out.println("You have " + Player.health + " health remaining.");
                        System.out.println("Will you Attack or Defend?");
                        action = scanner1.nextLine();
                        if(action.equals("Attack")){
                            Goblin.health = Goblin.health - Player.damage;
                            System.out.println("You've done " + Player.damage + " damage to Goblin. Goblin has "+ Goblin.health + " health remaining.");
                            continue;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            else if(action.equals("Defend")){
                System.out.println("You defended against the attack.");
                System.out.println("Goblin attacked you for " + Goblin.damage/2 + " damage.");
                System.out.println("You have " + Player.health + " health remaining.");
                Goblin.health = Goblin.health - Player.damage/2;
                System.out.println("You counter-attack for " + Player.damage/2 + " damage. Goblin has " + Goblin.health + " health remaining");
                Player.health = Player.health - Goblin.damage/2;
                    if(Goblin.health <= 0){
                        System.out.println("You have slain the Goblin! Continue to move forward.");
                        break;
                    }

                            else{
                                System.out.println("Will you Attack or Defend?");
                                action = scanner1.nextLine();
                                if(action.equals("Defend")){
                                    continue;
                                }                               
                        }
                }   
            }
        break;

    case 5:
        System.out.println("You've run into a goblin! Attack or Defend?");
        String action1 = scanner1.nextLine();
        while(Goblin.health > 0){
            if(action1.equals("Attack")){
                Goblin.health = Goblin.health - Player.damage;
                System.out.println("You've done " + Player.damage + " damage to Goblin. Goblin has "+ Goblin.health + " health remaining.");
                while(true){
                if(Goblin.health <= 0){
                    System.out.println("You have slain the Goblin! Continue to move forward.");
                    break;
                }
                    else{

                        Player.health = Player.health - Goblin.damage;
                        System.out.println("Goblin attacked you for " + Goblin.damage + " damage.");
                        System.out.println("You have " + Player.health + " health remaining.");
                        System.out.println("Will you Attack or Defend?");
                        action1 = scanner1.nextLine();
                        if(action1.equals("Attack")){
                            Goblin.health = Goblin.health - Player.damage;
                            System.out.println("You've done " + Player.damage + " damage to Goblin. Goblin has "+ Goblin.health + " health remaining.");
                            continue;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            else if(action1.equals("Defend")){
                System.out.println("You defended against the attack.");
                System.out.println("Goblin attacked you for " + Goblin.damage/2 + " damage.");
                System.out.println("You have " + Player.health + " health remaining.");
                Goblin.health = Goblin.health - Player.damage/2;
                System.out.println("You counter-attack for " + Player.damage/2 + " damage. Goblin has " + Goblin.health + " health remaining");
                Player.health = Player.health - Goblin.damage/2;
                    if(Goblin.health <= 0){
                        System.out.println("You have slain the Goblin! Continue to move forward.");
                        break;
                    }

                            else{
                                System.out.println("Will you Attack or Defend?");
                                action1 = scanner1.nextLine();
                                if(action1.equals("Defend")){
                                    continue;
                                }                               
                        }
                }   
            }
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("You've run into an Orc! Attack or Defend?");
        String action2 = scanner1.nextLine();
            while(Orc.health > 0){
                if(action2.equals("Attack")){
                    Orc.health = Orc.health - Player.damage;
                    System.out.println("You've done " + Player.damage + " damage to Orc. Orc has "+ Orc.health + " health remaining.");
                    while(true){
                    if(Orc.health <= 0){
                        System.out.println("You have slain the Orc! Continue to move forward.");
                        break;
                    }
                        else{

                            Player.health = Player.health - Orc.damage;
                            System.out.println("Orc attacked you for " + Orc.damage + " damage.");
                            System.out.println("You have " + Player.health + " health remaining.");
                            System.out.println("Will you Attack or Defend?");
                            action2 = scanner1.nextLine();
                            if(action2.equals("Attack")){
                                Orc.health = Orc.health - Player.damage;
                                System.out.println("You've done " + Player.damage + " damage to Orc. Orc has "+ Orc.health + " health remaining.");
                                continue;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if(action2.equals("Defend")){
                    System.out.println("You defended against the attack.");
                    System.out.println("Orc attacked you for " + Orc.damage/2 + " damage.");
                    System.out.println("You have " + Player.health + " health remaining.");
                    Orc.health = Orc.health - Player.damage/2;
                    System.out.println("You counter-attack for " + Player.damage/2 + " damage. Orc has " + Orc.health + " health remaining");
                    Player.health = Player.health - Orc.damage/2;
                        if(Orc.health <= 0){
                            System.out.println("You have slain the Goblin! Continue to move forward.");
                            break;
                        }

                                else{
                                    System.out.println("Will you Attack or Defend?");
                                    action2 = scanner1.nextLine();
                                    if(action2.equals("Defend")){
                                        continue;
                                    }                               
                            }
                    }   
                }
            roll = roll + 1;
        }
        }
            else{
                break;
            }

    }
}
```

Here is what the output is like.

```
Hello adventurer. What is your name?
Testrun
Ah, so your name is Testrun. Pleasure to meet you.
Sorry to say, but there are more pressing matters at hand.
The nearby town of Notsosafe has been overrun by monsters!
Please go and help clear out the monsters there.
What is your weapon of choice? The Sword and shield? Greatsword? or Staff?
Staff
Your stats are now:
Attack: 4
Health: 20

Now that you have selected your weapon, Go and save the town of Notsosafe!
4
You've run into a goblin! Attack or Defend?
Attack
You've done 4 damage to Goblin. Goblin has 1 health remaining.
Goblin attacked you for 1 damage.
You have 19 health remaining.
Will you Attack or Defend?
Attack
You've done 4 damage to Goblin. Goblin has -3 health remaining.
You have slain the Goblin! Continue to move forward.
You've run into a goblin! Attack or Defend?
Attack
You've run into a goblin! Attack or Defend?
Attack
You've run into a goblin! Attack or Defend?
Attack
You've run into a goblin! Attack or Defend?
```

After you kill the goblin off, it just loops the question instead of actually going back up and running the damage codes and such. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong with my **loop**? [...] Here is my code, **the entire thing**._

Comment: You've got like...3 loops in there.  Which loop are you talking about?

Comment: You should really break up your code into at least more functions...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention which. I believe the one i'm having problems with is the one encompassing the switch. Pardon me for posting the entire thing. I'm just not sure if I have any other errors in there.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you aren't resetting your Goblin's HP after it dies. Your code is pretty enormous, but here's the idea of why your code is not working as expected:

```java
// You only create a single Goblin instance in your scope
monster Goblin = new monster();
Goblin.name = "Goblin";
Goblin.health = 5;
Goblin.damage = 1;

...

while(true)
    if(roll < 10) {
        switch(randomNum) {
        ...
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You've run into a goblin! Attack or Defend?");
            String action = scanner1.nextLine();

            while(Goblin.health > 0) {
                if(action.equals("Attack")) {    
                    Goblin.health = Goblin.health - Player.damage;
                    System.out.println("You've done " + Player.damage + " damage to Goblin. Goblin has "+ Goblin.health + " health remaining.");
                    while(true){
                        if(Goblin.health <= 0){
                             System.out.println("You have slain the Goblin! Continue to move forward.");
                             break;
                        }
                    }

                } else if(action.equals("Defend")) {
                    // Redacted
                }
            }

            // You need to reset the Goblin's health here.
            break;
        case 5:
            ...
        }
    }
```

You never reset the Goblin's health anywhere!

The simple fix is to change the end of `case 4` to:

```java
case 4:
    // All your other handling here

    Goblin.health = 5;
    break;
case 5:
```

Answer (score 0):

[mauzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4458754/mauzel) is correct. You dont reset the health and hence its stuck in the loop

```
while(Goblin.health > 0)
```

I'd like to add more to the answer. Avoid using below always

```
while(true)
```

it results in an infinite loop if you do not break properly. Rather use a flag

```
    boolean something = true
    while(something)
    {
      //do something
    }
```

So you can easily set the flag to false whenever needed.

Also, when you enter the loop you've got

```
while(true)
        if(roll < 10){
}
```

I'd recommend remove `if` condition and change it to

```
while (roll != 10)
{
}
```

Try and break all the events into methods so it easy to debug and find problems and I  hope you are using debugger(this was easy to spot while debugging)

Comment: Sorry, I was just using the regular. I'm still very new to coding so I'm not familiar with all this. Thanks for the info. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `roll` is not incrementing, so you are endlessly evaluating the `switch(randomNum)` statement with an unchanging value of `randomNum`. This is why it keeps repeating the same case even after the enemy has been slain.